# Smooth input handling in Java

Tags: java, 2d, input

I am writing a Java game.

My problem is to get a really smooth input. If I hit the key <kbd>W</kbd> the character has to go forwards, but if I hit <kbd>A</kbd> and release the <kbd>W</kbd> key, the character doesn't go left ways :( .

It isn't smooth. Which ways are given in common game developing for a smooth input?

**My current source code** 
(Input.java): http://pastebin.com/9Z9qtXik
(MainLoop.handlingInputs): http://pastebin.com/Vx8BzSpL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0)` method you are marking all keys as released, not just the one which actually was released. The result is that when the player releases one key while still holding another, the other key will also be considered released.

You need to check `arg0` for the key which actually was released, just the way you already do in `keyPressed`.

Another thing which could cause problems is that you implemented both `keyPressed` and `keyTyped`. These two events behave very similar, so when you implement one, you usually have no reason to also implement the other. The main difference is that keyPressed reports modifier-keys like shift as separate events, while keyTyped reports visible characters entered. When you type a capital-A, `keyPressed` is called twice, first for <kbd>shift</kbd>, then for <kbd>a</kbd>. `keyTyped` is called for a single event <kbd>A</kbd>. For game input, `keyPressed` is usually more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using KeyBindings for smooth input handling! Right now it is true you have an error in your code as stated by @Phillipp, but KeyListening is not recommended to be used in games.

KeyBindings are a much newer update to Java and handle input much better that KeyListeners do. A quick Google search will provide you with more than enough sample code to learn it :)